# Outputs renderizados não aparecem no app Shiny usando Golem

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

Estou criando um Dashboard em `Shiny` utilizando os módulos do `Golem`.

Entretanto, as renderizações do servidor não estão aparecendo na UI.
Tudo que eu adiciono na UI do módulo aparece no app, exceto os outputs que são renderizado no servidor.

Segue exemplo da renderização de uma `datatable`.

O módulo:

```
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @importFrom shiny NS tagList
#' @import DT
mod_balanco_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  mainPanel(
    p('Esse texto aparece'),
    DT::dataTableOutput(ns("tablecars"))
 )
}

#' balanco Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_balanco_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns

    output$tablecars <- DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(mtcars)

    })

  })
}
```

O app ui

```r
#' @param request Internal parameter for `{shiny}`.
#'     DO NOT REMOVE.
#' @import shiny
#' @import bs4Dash
#' @noRd
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    # Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    # Your application UI logic

    bs4Dash::dashboardPage(
      title = "dashboard",
      dark = TRUE,
      scrollToTop = TRUE,
      bs4Dash::dashboardHeader(
      
        bs4Dash::dashboardSidebar(
        title = "Sidebar",
        bs4Dash::sidebarMenu(
          bs4Dash::menuItem(
            "BC",
            tabName = "bc",
            icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right"),
            bs4Dash::menuSubItem(
              "Balanço",
              tabName = "balanco",
              icon = shiny::icon("angle-double-right")
            )
        )
      ),
      bs4Dash::bs4DashBody(
        bs4Dash::tabItems(
          bs4Dash::tabItem(tabName = "balanco",
                           mod_balanco_ui("balanco_ui_1")
          )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Server ui

```r
#' The application server-side
#'
#' @param input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'     DO NOT REMOVE.
#' @import shiny
#' @noRd
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Your application server logic

  mod_balanco_server("balanco_ui_1")


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enfim, tentei tanta coisa que não sei se realmente foi isso que resolveu.

Mas depois que rodei os comandos abaixo, funcionou:

```r
golem::add_rstudioconnect_file()
golem::add_shinyappsio_file()
golem::add_shinyserver_file() 

golem::disable_autoload() # que em tese roda todos os de cima.
```

Esses comando impedem que o R rode os scripts em determinada ordem. Assim o `golem` roda de acordo com sua estrutura.

Mais informações: https://golemverse.org/post/golem-0.3.1-release-on-cran/